# What's the relation between GAE full-text-search Documents and database records?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

I'm trying to implement full text search in my GAE app. I've used a python framework (Web2py) to build the app and defined a "Table" of my contact list consisting of fields of name, phone, email etc.

After reading the documentation several times I still don't understand:

1. what's the relation between the search "Index" & "Document" class and database index (index.yaml) and records of the said table.
2. the search result contains contents in "Documents" or actual entries in the database

I guess I have to fully understand these concepts before I can head down to coding.

Any explanation will be greatly appreciate.

Spring

Answer (score 1):

There is no relationship. The full-text search store is completely separate from the datastore. It's up to you to define the structure of your FTS documents, and store a key that identifies the relevant datastore entity if you need to link them.